# MVC, use same View for multiple profiles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm making a game website and using GiantBombs.com API. I've finished a search function and on a search I get the results in a table.

I want every row to be a link to the "Game Profile" i want on the site.

My issue is I can't figure out how to give every game a unique URL, only using 1 View.

E.g:
Localhost/Gameprofile/XXX-XXX - where X is the "ID" property of the game on GiantBomb

For my **search** function I could use this which generate a URL based on the search.

```
<form method="get" action="/URL">
<input id="searchField" name="search">
<input type="hidden" id="myValue" value="@ViewBag.sq" />
```

However, I can't figure out how to do this on a Table.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all of the information about each game stored in a database table then you can do something like this:

You need to pass the games ID as a parameter to the function that loads your page.  For example:

```
//One Page
public ActionResult Gameprofile(int ID)
{
    //Query your database, to return only the related rows.
    //To do this you can refer to the parameter you just passed in.

    return View();
}
```

You can call the function from your index page like so:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Gameprofile", "ControllerName", new { .ID = "myValue"});
```

I'm not entirely certain that this is what you're aiming for, but hopefully it helps.

If you're new to mvc, there's plenty of help and advice on stack overflow and the MSDN.